# ImageMagick unable to open image and file

Tags: imagemagick, convert

I try to convert images to thumbnails with imagemagick. All works fine, so I will get a thumbnail. But I get some errors on my console:

```
convert: unable to open image `module':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2489.
convert: unable to open image `*':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2489.
convert: unable to open file `*':  @ error/blob.c/FileToBlob/831.
convert: unable to open image `*':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2489.
convert: unable to open file `*':  @ error/blob.c/FileToBlob/831.
convert: unable to open image `*':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2489.
convert: unable to open file `*':  @ error/blob.c/FileToBlob/831.
convert: unable to open image `*':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2489.
convert: unable to open file `*':  @ error/blob.c/FileToBlob/831.
convert: unable to open image `*':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2489.
convert: unable to open file `*':  @ error/blob.c/FileToBlob/831.
convert: unable to open image `*':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2489.
convert: unable to open file `*':  @ error/blob.c/FileToBlob/831.
convert: unable to open image `*':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2489.
convert: unable to open file `*':  @ error/blob.c/FileToBlob/831.
convert: unable to open image `*':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2489.
convert: unable to open file `*':  @ error/blob.c/FileToBlob/831.
```

All permissions are set correctly. I can't found any error like this at google or somewhere else. I hope someone have an idea:) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to give the command you're using.

The chances are, you've put a `*` within a `'`, so your command you should be:

```
convert -opts ... *
```

And not

```
convert -opts ... '*'
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. My Command look so:/usr/bin/convert module -quality 100 -antialias -geometry 220x220 -profile '*' -unsharp 0.5x1 "./../images/full/76/d042dab2.jpg" "./../images/thumbnails/76/d042dab2.jpg"

Comment: What is `-profile '*'` supposed to do? That's what is causing your problem.

Comment: I don't really know its from my gallery script. I remove that option and now everythink works like a charm:) thank you

Comment: Not a problem. If you get a chance, please can you mark the question as accepted by pressing the hollow grey tick under my answer? I'll prevent people opening the question thinking it's unanswered and trying to help.